# delete columns from an exported table

Tags: c#, .net

For the application  i have builded, i have made the followig function to allow the tables export to csv:

```
`protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
    String names = (String)Session["names"];
    DataRow total = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]; 
    List<string> colSaved = new List<string>();

    for (int n = dt.Columns.Count -1 ; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        if (total[n].ToString() != "0")
        { 
            colSaved.Add(dt.Columns[n].ColumnName);

        }
    }

    string[] columns = colSaved.ToArray();
    DataTable newTable;
    newTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable( false, columns);
    String[] content = new String[newTable.Rows.Count + 1];

    string temp1 = "";
    content[0] = names;

    for (int i =0; i<newTable.Rows.Count;i++)
```

{
        temp1 = "";

```
    for (int j = 0; j < newTable.Columns.Count; j++)
{

    temp1 += "\"" + newTable.Rows[i][j] + "\",";
    content[i + 1] = temp1;
}
```

}

```
    string name = DateTime.Now.Year + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Day +      "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + DateTime.Now.Second + "" +  DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "__" + ".csv";
   System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/export/" + name), content);
```

Response.Redirect("~/export/" + name);

```
}`
```

where dt is a pivoted datatable. the problem is that in the application i have deleted the columns with value '0', but in the exported file, they do appear. i need a function to delete this columns also from the exported table. can anybody help me?

Comment: what do you mean by `columns with value '0'`. Columns don't have values

Comment: Where do you have removed the columns? If you have still them in your datatable then you haven't removed from the datatable but from somewhere else. If you know the names of the columns removed then you could remove them also from the DataTable before the loop

Comment: @Alireza in the original datatable the cells had numeric values. if each row of a column contains only 0 values, then the entire column is removed. the point is that when i exported the table on CSV, i cannot remove this columns

Comment: @Steve the removed columns change in dependence of a date interval condition, and i remove them on the original datatable,  so the indexes are never the same, that is  why i have difficulties

Comment: Ok. I get it. Is it OK to loop and remove the columns before exporting the `DataTable`?

Comment: @Alireza i already tried that, but is not working. i am thinkin of session the removed columns, but i am not quite sure how....

Comment: Can you update the question and show me how you did that? It should've worked

Comment: just a sec, i got you wrong. i thought you were saying in the loop in the datatable, not in the function. let me try the function and then if is not working i will update it  OK?

Comment: @Alireza i updated it, check if i am doing something wrong...

Comment: @Alireza it seems right, but is not working...

Comment: are you sure the total row's values are correct? have you checked them?

Comment: @Alireza i debugged the program, now the problem is that the rows  returned are the same as in the original table, but in the file appear also the ones that have been removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
    String names = (String)Session["names"];
    DataRow total = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]; //rreshti i fundit
    List<string> colSaved = new List<string>();

    for (int n = dt.Columns.Count-1; n >=0; n--)

    {

        if (total[n].ToString() != "0")  
            colSaved.Add(dt.Columns[n].ColumnName);


    }

string[] columns = colSaved.ToArray();

DataTable newTable;
newTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columns);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",",columns.Reverse()));

foreach (DataRow r in newTable.Rows)
{

         sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", r.ItemArray.Reverse()));
}
string name = DateTime.Now.Year + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + DateTime.Now.Second + "" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "__" + ".csv";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/export/" + name), sb.ToString());
Response.Redirect("~/export/" + name);
```

}

here is the function, it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a DataTable with columns A, B, C, D and now you want a different instance of the DataTable with the same rows but only with columns A, B, D (C has been removed as from your requirements)

```
DataTable dt = GetTable(); //This is the table with A, B, C and D columns....

string[] columns = new string[] {"A", "B", "D"};
DataTable newTable;   // This will have only A, B, and D
newTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable("tempTableName", false, columns);
```

The problem as you can see is to know the names of the columns that you want to keep from the original source.

[MSDN on DataView.ToTable methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then the loop to prepare the string array could be rewritten in this way

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(Session["names"].ToString());

foreach(DataRow r in newTable.Rows)
{
    sb.AppendLine("\"" + string.Join("\",", r.ItemArray) + "\"");
}
string name = DateTime.Now.Year + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + DateTime.Now.Second + "" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "__" + ".csv";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/export/" + name), sb.ToString());
Response.Redirect("~/export/" + name);
```

**EDIT** After your update above, obtaining the names of the column to preserve in the new table is relatively easy

```
List<string> colSaved = new List<string>();
for (int n = dt.Columns.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
{
    if (total[n].ToString() != "0")
        colSaved.Add(dt.Columns[n].ColumnName);
}
.....
.....
string[] columns = colSaved.ToArray();
```

This will leave the original table (dt and the Session variable) with the original columns, while the newTable will contain the rows of only the columns saved.

Notice that if you loop over a collection to remove some element from it, it is better to start from the last element of the collection and loop toward the first element, removing elements from the tail of the collection (no need to adjust the for indexer)

Comment: the  datatable receives its data from a database, and their depend on the dates i choose to show the data, so is never certain which columns will be removed

Comment: it works, however, the table is not formatted, it just results on a one column table,

Comment: What do you mean for _not formatted_. You should have a series of lines (one for each row) where every field is enclosed in double quotations and separated by a comma.

Comment: the point is that the header is missing, and also the text is aligned from the right to the left...

Comment: Added the Session["Names"] to the StringBuilder, for the alignment could you show an example?

Comment: i edited the function you gave me, now i am updating it and tell me where am i going wrong...

Comment: for the alignment, it does not appear from 1-10 but from 10-1, in reverse order...

Comment: i figure out the part of the reversed order, but whenever ii want to put the header with the session["names"], it always appears another column that should have been deleted, for example, if they  are A,B,C,D,E and should appear A,B,C   it appears like A,B,C,E